# Casting in java, technical info

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, casting

I'm trying to understand what happend when someone casts an object of one specific class to another class. I.e there are two classes

```
 public class Aclass{

   private String attribute1;

   private List<String> attribute2;

   //get/set methods

 }

 public class Bclass{

   private String attribute1;

   private List<int> attribute2;

   //get/set methods

 }
```

Now inside another class i have both these objects and afterwards i cast them.

```
public class Cclass{

   Aclass aclass=new Aclass();

   //returneddata is a method that returns an Aclass object that contained dta for the Aclass attributes
   aclass=returneddata();

   Bclass bclass=new Bclass();


   bclass=Bclass.class.cast(aclass);

}
```

From the aforementioned class i'm taking a java.lang.ClassCastException.

The problem is that i have two classes which does not contained only two attributes each but contained both of them 20. The 16 of these atributes are common in both classes.

Moreover the returneddata method returns an object retrieved from a repository. As you can understand i want to find a way and transfer the 16 data attributes of the object Aclass to the object Bclass.

I want:

1) To find a way to rewrite the 16 common attributes data from the one object to the other

2) How the cast is working in general

Any propositions?

Comment: What is the purpose/goal of this? There are many ways to do what you'd like to do, but the best depends on your intent.

Comment: So what are you asking?  Are you trying to figure out why you're getting class cast exceptions?

Comment: But casting certainly doesn't work this way. Casting is based on an explicit `is a` relationship between the two classes and not on common attributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact that both classes have similar attributes does not matter. What matters is that `Aclass` and `Bclass` are not related to each other: one is not a superclass of the other. If you want to share or move data between these classes, you'll need to copy the data from one instance to another yourself.

#### A casting example

Let's say we have an object `Fruit fruit = new Banana();`. Now if you'd need to call a method of `Banana` later in the code, you can cast `fruit` with the cast `(Banana)`. Why? Because you happen to know that `fruit` is a `Banana` but the Java compiler does not know that (it thinks it's a `Fruit` and it could also be a different fruit). So you have to add the cast to add additional information about `fruit` and to perform the operation safely.

Comment: I think, possibly, the asker is hoping for a Java equivalent of reinterpret_cast . . . which thankfully doesn't exist. +1 for being spot on.

Answer (score 2):

The two classes Aclass and Bclass does not have a common super class or interface hence the ClassCastException. In this particular case you could use BeanUtils, http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/, to copy the common properties from Aclass to Bclass.

Comment: +1 for BeanUtils#copyProperties which will "solve" one of his problems.

Answer (score 2):

Java classes and interfaces form a DAG based on their relationships defined by the `extends` or `implements` keywords.

If `A extends B` or `A implements B`, then B is a direct superclass or superinterface of A.
If A is a direct superclass/interface of B and B is likewise to C, then A is an indirect   superclass/interface of C.
The `java.lang.Object` class is the superclass of every class.

An object of class A can only be cast to B if B is a superclass/interface of A (or when A and B are the same class).

There are also some special rules for certain constructs (arrays, primitive types) but the above rules should make it clear why your cast isn't working.

A complete description can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1).

Answer (score 2):

The best solution here would be write super class that contains the common elements of both classes and then have each of your subclasses extend the super class, that way you could have a list of type SuperClass

```
public class SuperClass{
   protected String att1_common;
   protected List<String> att2_common;
}

import SuperClass
public class Aclass extends SuperClass {
   private String uniqueAtt1; 
   //get/set methods
}

import SuperClass
public class Bclass extends superClass{
   private String uniqueAtt1;
   //get/set methods
}
```

note the protected scope modifier, this means private except to subclasses

so now:

```
List<SuperClass> listofstuff;
try{ Aclass item = listofstuff[0];}
catch( java.lang.ClassCastException e){try Bclass item = listofstuff[0];}
```